# If statement not working (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, if-statement, canvas

I have a code that classifies a point 1 if it's above the line y=x, and -1 if it's below the line y=x. I draw the line in canvas of y=x(Since the y axis is inverted in canvas it looks like y=-x). Then I draw each point, and if it's 1 I paint it green, if it's -1 I paint it red. I would expect to see a straight line with one side being green and one side being red. I ran the code and I got a weird result.

Here's the code for how I label my points:

```
function Point(x, y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.label = 0;
    if(this.y >= this.x){
        this.label = 1;
        console.log(x, y, "UP");
    }else if(this.y < this.x){
        this.label = -1;
        console.log(x, y, "Down");
    }
}
```

Here's the code to paint the points:

```
function draw(){
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, can1.width, can1.height);
  ctx.strokeStyle = "yellow";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(can1.width, can1.height);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
  for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++){
    var x = points[i].x;
    var y = points[i].y;
    if(points[i].label == 1){
        var color = "Chartreuse";
    }else{
        var color = "red";
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
}
```

I then run it in the browser and I get this:
[image: What I see in the browser]

It seems to be kind of working, but not fully?

Edit: The x and y values are assigned randomly in other parts of the code.

Please help and thanks!

Comment: If you click `<>` you can create a [mcve]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may draw the yellow line to the wanted `x === y` and not just to the end of the canvas.

```
ctx.lineTo(Math.min(can1.width, can1.height), Math.min(can1.width, can1.height));
```

Comment: Wow, this is working, But I don't understand why?  What does Math.min do?

Comment: it takes the smallest value of the arguments.

Comment: So for the x coordinate, you're taking the smallest value between the height and width of the canvas and for the y coordinate you're doing the same...

Comment: OHHH, So the original code doesn't work because the canvas is not perfectly square but a rectangle... Thanks so much I get it now.

Comment: right, you get a diagonal line, even if you change the ratio of the canvas

Comment: yup, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to explain the same thing in a different way.

```
ctx.lineTo(can1.width, can1.height);
```

This code will work as long as width = height. This is because the problem is plotting points above and below y=x. y=x, as everyone knows is the equation of a straight line (y=mx+c where m =1 and c = 0). We need two points to plot a line. In the case of ctx.lineTo, it always starts with (x,y) =  (0,0) which is left top corder. Now in the question, whenever width and height are different, there will be errors. In the answer,  the Math min function is used in such a way that the line is plotted with x=y. But I would suggest to use the following the max function so that all the points are covered in the maximum value of x and y provided x,y are always less than width and height.

```
ctx.lineTo(Math.max(can1.width, can1.height), Math.max(can1.width, can1.height));
```

For those who want to run the full code and see the result, the code is given below:

https://gist.github.com/harisnp/320462ab20eafd3f36826bee6458ac8c

See the result with max below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Use cross product.

The following function will return -1 if a point is left of a line 0 if the points is on the line and 1 if the point is right of the line.

```
// x1, y1 start of line
// x2, y2 end of line
// px1, py1 the point to test
function testPointToLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, px1, px2){
    return (x2 - x1) * (py1 - y1) - (y2 - y1) * (px1 - x1);
}
```

If the line always starts at 0,0 you can simplify

```
function testFromOriginPointToLine(x2, y2, px1, px2){
    return x2 * py1 - y2 * px1;
}
```

Both functions just return the cross product of the line as a vector, and the vector from the start of the line to the point

### The fix

Thus you can change your point function as follows and the aspect of the canvas will not matter

```
function Point(x, y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.label = canvas.width * y - canvas.height * x <= 0 ? 1 : -1;
}
```

### An Example

```js
requestAnimationFrame(addPoints);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

 // random function
const rand = (min=1,max=min+(min=0))=>Math.random()*(max-min)+min;   

function sizeCanvas() { // set canvas size
    canvas.width = innerWidth;
    canvas.height = innerHeight;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    ctx.lineTo(0,0);  // dont need beginPath as resize resets context
    ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.stroke();
}

function drawPoint(point){
    ctx.fillStyle = point.label > 0 ? "red" : "#0F0";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(point.x, point.y, 4, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();
}

function Point(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.label = canvas.width * y - canvas.height * x <= 0 ? 1 : -1;
}

function addPoints(){
    if (canvas.width !== innerWidth || canvas.height !== innerHeight) { sizeCanvas() }
    drawPoint(new Point(rand(canvas.width), rand(canvas.height)));
    requestAnimationFrame(addPoints);
}
```

```css
canvas {position : absolute; top : 0px; left : 0px; background : black;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Wow, that's pretty interesting. Thanks for the suggestion!